# SQL statement "Cannot Insert/Update more than one row" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update a column in a table and I am getting the following error:

> Cannot Insert/Update more than one row in dealorder
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Is there something wrong with the update statement? I know that there is more than one deal that has this webusersid, but should it not update it with the new one on all of them? Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE do
SET webusersid = 'X00HDX4G'
from dealorder do
where webusersid = 'B00FF5OR'
```

Comment: Why is the word DO in there?

Comment: your update statement is fine, it is your trigger on the table dealorder that fails

Comment: Thanks and yes confirmed. There is a trigger on the dealorder table. Does that mean I would need to create a cursor to loop though each of the dealorders?

Comment: no, it means you need to fix your trigger

Answer (score 3):

You have a trigger on `dealorder` table preventing update of several rows at once. Could be a replication set up on the table.

Comment: Yes this database is replicated. Is there a way I can perform this? Would I create a temp table to store all dealorders and webusersid and then create a cursor and update it one by one?

Comment: This might help: http://sqlserverscribbles.com/tag/msg-3609-level-16-state-1-procedure-trg_mssync_upd_state-line/